# I get the following error when I try to run a cgi script using webserver: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python-3.5

Here is the cgi script script I am attempting to run:

```
print("Content-type: text/plain\n")
print("Hello, world!")
```

after staring up this server:

```
#! python3
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer
from http.server import CGIHTTPRequestHandler

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address=('',8002)
    httpd=server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer is correct but I renamed my CGi script in \cgi-bin from hello.cgi to hello.py and now it runs correctly with no errors.
I got this idea from John Gaines Jr answer to post "CGI Script is not executable".